# Find all paths from leafs to each node in a forest

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, tree

I asked this question in parts, because I didn't have enough infromations, but now that I have, I can ask the full question. So I have data in text file which has 2 columns. First column is a predecessor and second is a successor. I load the data using this code:

```
[line.split() for line in open('data.txt', encoding ='utf-8')]
```

Lets say that our data looks like this in a file:

```
ANALYTICAL_BALANCE BFG_DEPOSIT 
CUSTOMER_DETAIL BALANCE 
BFG_2056 FFD_15 
BALANCE BFG_16 
BFG_16 STAT_HIST 
ANALYTICAL_BALANCE BFG_2056 
CUSTOM_DATA AND_11 
AND_11 DICT_DEAL 
DICT_DEAL BFG_2056
```

and after loading

```
[[ANALYTICAL_BALANCE,BFG_DEPOSIT],
[CUSTOMER_DETAIL,BALANCE],
[BFG_2056, FFD_15],
[BALANCE,BFG_16],
[BFG_16,STAT_HIST],
[ANALYTICAL_BALANCE,BFG_2056],
[CUSTOM_DATA,AND_11],
[AND_11,DICT_DEAL],
[DICT_DEAL,BFG_2056]]
```

Then I want to connect this data. I create the adjency list:

```
def create_adj(edges):
    adj = {}   # or use defaultdict(list) to avoid `if` in the loop below
    for a, b in edges:
        if not a in adj:
            adj[a] = []
        if not b in adj:
            adj[b] = []
        adj[a].append(b)
    return adj
```

and the get all the paths:

```
def all_paths(adj):
    def recur(path):
        node = path[-1]
        neighbors = [neighbor for neighbor in adj[node] if not neighbor in path]
        if not neighbors:
            yield path
        for neighbor in neighbors:
            yield from recur(path + [neighbor])

    for node in adj:
        yield from recur([node])
```

so the output looks like this:

```
data = [
    ["ANALYTICAL_BALANCE","BFG_DEPOSIT"],
    ["CUSTOMER_DETAIL","BALANCE"],
    ["BFG_2056", "FFD_15"],
    ["BALANCE","BFG_16"],
    ["BFG_16","STAT_HIST"],
    ["ANALYTICAL_BALANCE","BFG_2056"],
    ["CUSTOM_DATA","AND_11"],
    ["AND_11","DICT_DEAL"],
    ["DICT_DEAL","BFG_2056"]
]

adj = create_adj(data)

print([path for path in all_paths(adj) if len(path) > 1])


[ANALYTICAL_BALANCE,BFG_DEPOSIT]
[CUSTOMER_DETAIL,BALANCE,BFG_16,STAT_HIST]
[BFG_2056,FFD_15]
[BALANCE,BFG_16,STAT_HIST]
[ANALYTICAL_BALANCE,BFG_2056,FFD_15]
[CUSTOM_DATA,AND_11,DICT_DEAL,BFG_2056,FFD_15]
[AND_11,DICT_DEAL,BFG_2056,FFD_15]
[DICT_DEAL,BFG_2056,FFD_15]
```

We can visualize the connections as a separate trees which creates the forest. The trees won't have any cycles, because of nature of the input data.
[image: Connections Visualization]

Now my question is. **How can I get every connection from leaf to every node for every tree ?** What I mean by that. We have 3 trees so I will start from the top one.

```
Tree1:
ANALYTICAL_BALANCE BFG_DEPOSIT

Tree2:
ANALYTICAL_BALANCE BFG_2056
ANALYTICAL_BALANCE FFD_15
CUSTOM_DATA AND_11
CUSTOM_DATA DICT_DEAL
CUSTOM_DATA BFG_2056
CUSTOM_DATA FFD_15

Tree3:
CUSTOMER_DETAIL BALANCE
CUSTOMER_DETAIL BFG_16
CUSTOMER_DETAIL STAT_HIST
```

As you can see, my first try was to create list of adjacencies and find all paths. Then I would delete the connections beetwen the nodes that are not leafs and filter the data. It was fine for input of 150 rows, but when I inputted the full file with 13k rows the code was compiling for 2 days without any signs of coming to an end. So I'm looking for most efficient code or algorithm as well as best data type for my job(Lists, Data Frames etc. ). Any help would be greatly appreciated, because I'm fighting with it for a few days now and I can't find any idea on how to solve this problem. If something is not clear I will edit the post. 
The data will be saved into excel file with openpyxl so when I filter by successor **I can see every leaf in predecessor column that is connected to this successor**.
Here is my whole code.

```
# create adjacencies
def create_adj(edges):
    adj = {}
    for a, b in edges:
        if not a in adj:
            adj[a] = []
        if not b in adj:
            adj[b] = []
        adj[a].append(b)
    return adj
 
# find all paths
def all_paths(adj):
    def recur(path):
        node = path[-1]
        neighbors = [neighbor for neighbor in adj[node] if not neighbor in path]
        if not neighbors:
            yield path
        for neighbor in neighbors:
            yield from recur(path + [neighbor])
 
    for node in adj:
        yield from recur([node])
 
# delete the  connections from list 
def conn_deletion(list, list_deletion):
    after_del = [x for x in list if x[0] not in list_deletion]
    return after_del
 
 # get paths where len of path is > 2 and save them as a leaf to node. Also save connections to deletion.
def unpack_paths(my_list):
    list_of_more_succ = []
    to_deletion = []
    for item in my_list:
        if len(item) == 1:
            print("len 1",item)
            to_deletion.append(item[0])
        elif len(item) > 2:
            for i in range(1, len(item) - 1):
                to_deletion.append(item[i])
                print("len > 2", item[i])
                if [item[0], item[i]] in list_of_more_succ:
                    pass
                else:
                    list_of_more_succ.append([item[0], item[i]])
    list_concat = my_list + list_of_more_succ
    sorted_list = list(k for k, _ in itertools.groupby(list_concat))
    final = conn_deletion(sorted_list, list(dict.fromkeys(to_deletion)))
    return final
 
 
data = [line.split() for line in open('data.txt', encoding='utf-8')]
 
adj = create_adj(data)
print(adj)
 
workbook = Workbook()
sheet = workbook.active
sheet["A1"] = "Source"
sheet["B1"] = "Child"
 
loaded = list(all_paths(adj))
 
final_edited = unpack_paths(loaded)
 
# Save data to excel file. We don't want paths with len == 1 or > 2.
for row, item in enumerate(final_edited, start=2):
    if len(item) > 2:
        pass
    elif len(item) == 1:
        pass
    else:
        sheet[f"A{row}"] = item[0]
        sheet[f"B{row}"] = item[1]
workbook.save("DataMap.xlsx")
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand the question. Are you asking for all pairs of vertices `(u, v)` so that there is a path from `u` to `v`? Note that the output might contain up to `O(|V|^2)` pairs (when the whole graph is a single path).

Comment: I want paths from leaf to every node in a tree, without node to node paths. So instead of this path: [CUSTOM_DATA,AND_11,DICT_DEAL,BFG_2056,FFD_15] I want to get: [CUSTOM_DATA, AND_11], [CUSTOM_DATA, DICT_DEA],[CUSTOM_DATA, BFG_2056],[CUSTOM_DATA, FFD_15]

Comment: As far as I can see, your solution runs in O(|V|^2) which can finish in a couple of seconds for13k rows. Maybe you have a flaw in your implementation. For example, how do you delete the connections between nodes and nodes that are not leafs?

Comment: The filter logic is not quite clear. Maybe add the filter logic as you do it in your code, in relation to the functions you've already posted, and it might shed light on some questions.

Comment: I added whole code. I'm nearly sure that "unpack_paths" is the reason why it takes so long, but I don't know how to delete connections in more efficient way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest changing `all_paths` to `leaf_paths`, meaning that it would only yield those paths that start at a leaf.

Then use those paths to:

- Identify the root it leads to (the last element in the path)
- Identify the leaf (the first element in the path)
- Iterate all non-leaves in that path and combine each of them in a pair with the leaf.
- Store these pairs in a dictionary that is keyed by the root

Here is how you would alter `all_paths` at two places marked with a comment:

```
def leaf_paths(adj):
    def recur(path):
        node = path[-1]
        neighbors = [neighbor for neighbor in adj[node] if not neighbor in path]
        if not neighbors:
            yield path
        for neighbor in neighbors:
            yield from recur(path + [neighbor])

    # identify the internal nodes (not leaves)
    internals = set(parent for parents in adj.values() for parent in parents) 
    for node in adj:
        if not node in internals:  # require that the starting node is a leaf
            yield from recur([node])
```

Then add this function:

```
def all_leaf_pairs(paths):
    trees = {}

    for path in paths:
        if len(path) > 1:
            root = path[-1]
            if not root in trees:
                trees[root] = []
            it = iter(path)
            leaf = next(it)
            trees[root].extend((leaf, node) for node in it)
    return trees
```

And your main program would do:

```
data = [
    ["ANALYTICAL_BALANCE","BFG_DEPOSIT"],
    ["CUSTOMER_DETAIL","BALANCE"],
    ["BFG_2056", "FFD_15"],
    ["BALANCE","BFG_16"],
    ["BFG_16","STAT_HIST"],
    ["ANALYTICAL_BALANCE","BFG_2056"],
    ["CUSTOM_DATA","AND_11"],
    ["AND_11","DICT_DEAL"],
    ["DICT_DEAL","BFG_2056"]
]

adj = create_adj(data)
paths = leaf_paths(adj)

import pprint
pprint.pprint(all_leaf_pairs(paths))
```

This will output:

```
{'BFG_DEPOSIT': [('ANALYTICAL_BALANCE', 'BFG_DEPOSIT')],
 'FFD_15': [('ANALYTICAL_BALANCE', 'BFG_2056'),
            ('ANALYTICAL_BALANCE', 'FFD_15'),
            ('CUSTOM_DATA', 'AND_11'),
            ('CUSTOM_DATA', 'DICT_DEAL'),
            ('CUSTOM_DATA', 'BFG_2056'),
            ('CUSTOM_DATA', 'FFD_15')],
 'STAT_HIST': [('CUSTOMER_DETAIL', 'BALANCE'),
               ('CUSTOMER_DETAIL', 'BFG_16'),
               ('CUSTOMER_DETAIL', 'STAT_HIST')]}
```

### Explanation of `leaf_paths`

This function uses recursion. It defines `recur` in its scope.

But the main code starts with identifying the internal nodes (i.e. the nodes that have at least one child). Since `adj` provides the parent(s) for a given node, we just have to collect all those parents.

We use this set of internal nodes to make sure we start the recursion only on leaf nodes, as in the output we want to have paths that always start out with a leaf node.

The `recur` function will walk from the given leaf towards any root it can find. It extends the path with the next parent it can find (`neighbor`) and performs recursion until there is no more parent (i.e., it is a root). When that happens the accumulated path (that starts with a leaf and ends with a root) is *yielded*.

`leaf_paths` itself yields any path that `recur` yields.

Comment: Hi again ! I used your answer for a bigger data(my famous 13k rows text file) and I got MemoryError. The error happened on this line: trees[root].extend((leaf, node) for node in it) in all_leaf_pairs function.

Comment: I suppose it is quite demanding for memory. Imagine how many paths exist in that tree, and then how many leaf-node pairs exist. You could output `len(trees[root])` just before that line to have an idea of the size involved.

Comment: So I guess that there isn't any good solution to this problem, which isn't a "use faster pc" solution ?

Comment: I don't know. Without seeing your data, I cannot tell.

Comment: I think that showing you the text file with successors and predecessors wouldn't help much and I can't even, because the file is on my business laptop. I was thinking more about something like multithreading/multiprocessing. Maybe processing the input in batches, but I'm afraid that It could  mess up something with adjacencies. I think It's time for another question to my fellow stack-magicians.

Comment: Hey. Sorry for digging up this thread, but I'm tring do understand the code behind leaf_paths function. Can you maybe explain It more in depth ?

Comment: I added a section on that. Let me know what exactly you want to be explained more.

Comment: Your explanation is great. Thanks! I have last question(more of a kind request to be honest). I tried loading the data in chunks of 1000, but I got only to 59,000 out of 74,000,000 after full day of running. Do you maybe have better idea how I can process that ? My whole  code is here <https://pastebin.com/DUY2UDqx>. (It's set on 150 right now)

Comment: Check whether the performance issue is caused by writing that data to an Excel sheet one cell at a time. There are ways in Excel to dump a whole 2-D array on a sheet in one go. Not sure that is the bottleneck, but please check.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for not answering, but I was on vacation. I don't know if It's good practise to still add comment and asking for stuff so If not just tell me. I checked without the Excel loading and It takes still few days to compile(It takes 95% of  my 16 RAM). I was thinking maybe just create the paths from leaf to root. Then just creating list with every connections from leaf to every element in given path, because 74,000,000 paths seem to much even for 1300 rows in file.

Comment: My question is: what are you going to do with so much data? How will it serve you?

Comment: The data map is really just a lineage saved in Excel as Source-Child connection. The problem that I'm facing is that I know which element is connected to which because I can check it in Excel file, but It's hard to get which element is the primary feed for every element. As in graphic in my original post. I can easily find connections from "CUSTOM_DATA" to "FFD_15", but if I start searching from "FFD_15" from excel file via sorting I have to go all the way back instead of having just "CUSTOM_DATA":"FFD_15" connection and the same is other way. If I want to know what "CUSTOM_DATA" feed into.

Comment: I think you should just stick with the tree, possibly with bidirectional links (parents vs. children) and do the search at the time it is needed. The number of paths has a quadratic order of magnitude to the number of nodes in the tree. So retrieving all of them and storing them is going to have a huge impact.